# How to action link a route with several folders, not only controller and action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, html.actionlink

I know I can action link a route like this:

```
 // GET: Home
    [Route("Home/About/{text}/{a}/{b?}/{c?}")]
    public ActionResult About(string text, string a, string b, string c)
    {
      ViewBag.Message = text + a + b + c;
      return View();
    }
```

by doing this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("GO", "About", "Home", new {text = "Test", a="value1",b="value2",c="value3" },null)
```

but what if I want to action link something like this?

```
 // GET: Home
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{text}/{a}/{b?}/{c?}")]
    public ActionResult About(string text, string a, string b, string c)
    {
      ViewBag.Message = text + a + b + c;
      return View();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add route name to your action:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{text}/{a}/{b?}/{c?}", Name ="AboutRoute")]
    public ActionResult About(string text, string a, string b, string c)
    {
      ViewBag.Message = text + a + b + c;
      return View();
    }
```

and use the name :

```
@Html.RouteLink("GO","AboutRoute", new {
                        text = "Test", 
                        a="value1",
                           b="value2",
                       c="value3" } )
```

I tested it using Visual studio and it works properly.

And by the way you call this action by 2 ways.

1.Using Route Link and route name

2. Using another input control or httpclient or ajax or postman by url
   .../api/..controllerName../..actionName../..route values...

Comment: yes I tried it, but then it sends me to "https://localhost:44394/Home/AboutRoute".  And actually I want to go to https://localhost:44394/api/[controller]/[action], being by the way [controller] not equal to "Home".

Comment: It is not about what is your url looks like. It is about to call the right action of the right controller with the right route values.